# Link to specific position of page after the external link is clicked

Tags: php, jquery, html

I was wondering if its possible to move to specific position of the page after i clicked in external link.

Suppose i has a link like: `<a href="another_page.html">Go there</a>`. After i clicked in `'Go there'`, I want to move to specific position of `another_page.html`. Position may be at buttom or center or any other position. Is it possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can go to any position of the page by referring the element **id** like,

```
<a href="another_page.html#position">Go there</a>
```

Create a `div` with `id="position"` on page `another_page.html` as,

```
<div id="position">
```

It will points to the `position` div

Answer (score 2):

You can use [HTML's anchors](http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/struct/links.html):

Example

Main Page:

```
<a href="test1.html#John">John</a>
<a href="test1.html#Doe">Doe</a>
```

Sample Page:

```
<div id='John'></div>
<div id='Doe'></div>
```

Comment: The end tag for `<a>` elements is mandatory, and the use of the `name` attribute on `<a>` elements was deprecated in XHTML 1.0 (after the use of `id` on any element replaced it in HTML 4).

Answer (score 1):

You can use an href with the '#' to link to an element with a specific id:

```
<a href="another_page.html#gothere">Go There</a>
```

Where another_page.html has an element with

```
id="gothere"
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use the id of the link as the reference to achieve this!!

say: `<a href="another_page.html#mylink">Go there</a>` and in the page `another_page.html`, create the mentioned `id`(ex: `<p id="mylink">Mylink<p>`)

[Sample Link](http://www.w3schools.com/html/tryit.asp?filename=tryhtml_links_bookmark)

Answer (score 0):

```
<a href="#section">Section part></a>
When click on the anchor then it will be redirect on this section which is mentioned below.

<div id="section">
Hi I am websolutionexpert
You can follow me.
</div>
```

Comment: this is only internal link. Question is not about this.